# Java Regular expression to find out the number of matching words

Tags: java, regex

I am learning regular expression.Suppose, If I have two String like `abcd` & `bcdd`. To make them equal Strings I have to remove `a` from first and `d` from last string. is this possible to count the matched number like `bcd`=> (3).

Currently, I am doing this

```
Pattern p= Pattern.compile("["+abcd+"]{2}");
Matcher m= p.matcher("abcd bcdd");
```

My current solution doesn't provide me the correct result. So, my question

1) Is this possible ?

2) If possible, then how can I achieve that ?

Hope, you will help to increase my regular expression knowledge.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why you would use regex at all, if all you need is the number of "bcd"s. I've put both a non-regex and regex version here for comparison.

```
import  java.util.regex.Matcher;
import  java.util.regex.Pattern;
/**
   <P>{@code java BcdRegexXmpl}</P>
 **/
public class BcdRegexXmpl  {
   public static final void main(String[] igno_red)  {
      String sSentence = "abcd bcdd";
      int iBcds = 0;
      int iIdx = 0;
      while(true)  {
         int iBcdIdx = sSentence.indexOf("bcd", iIdx);
         if(iBcdIdx == -1)  {
            break;
         }
         iIdx = iBcdIdx + "bcd".length();
         iBcds++;
      }

      System.out.println("Number of 'bcd's (no regex): " + iBcds);

      //Alternatively

      iBcds = 0;
      //Same regex as @la-comadreja, with word-boundaries 
      //(for multiple "bcd"-s in a single word, remove the "\\b"-s)
      Matcher m = Pattern.compile("\\b\\w*bcd\\w*\\b").matcher(sSentence);
      while(m.find())  {
         System.out.println("Found at index " + m.start());
         iBcds++;
      }
      System.out.println("Number of 'bcd's (with regex): " + iBcds);
   }
}
```

Output:

```
[R:\jeffy\programming\sandbox\xbnjava]java BcdRegexXmpl
Number of 'bcd's (no regex): 2
Found at index 0
Found at index 5
Number of 'bcd's (with regex): 2
```

Comment: I like your indexOf() based answer.  You don't need to split the non-Regex string into words anymore though.

Answer (score 0):

Your pattern should be:

```
(a?)(bcd)(d?)
```

Another possibility is to write it as

```
\w*bcd\w*
```

If you want to count the number of "bcd"s in the string:

```
int bcds = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < str.length() - 2; i++) {
    if (str.charAt(i) == 'b' && str.charAt(i+1) == 'c' && str.charAt(i+2) == 'd') 
        bcds++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A maximally generalizable, concise and readable (and reasonably efficient) non-Regex answer:

```
int countMatches(String s, String searchStr) {
    //Here, s is "abcd bcdd" and searchStr is "bcd"

    int matches = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < s.length() - searchStr.length() + 1; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < searchStr.length(); j++) {
            if (s.charAt(i + j) != searchStr.charAt(j)) break;
            if (j == searchStr.length() - 1) matches++;
        }
    }
    return matches;
}
```